# Elastic Beanstalk eb init Error processing line 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Everytime I run an eb command on my terminal,I'm having this error at the top:

```
Error processing line 1 of /Users/lorenzojoaquin/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 152, in addpackage
      exec line
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Users/lorenzojoaquin/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/__init__.py", line 194
      f'spec_for_{name}',
                       ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Remainder of file ignored
```

I installed it using the [recommended method cloning the github repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup)
I imagine it has something to do with the installation but I couldn't make it work.

Yesterday I uploaded something to Elastic Beanstalk without problems, but today something changed

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your Elastic Beanstalk is using an older version of python which does not support f-string literals. So one of the ways to deal with this is to locate and open the 'init.py' file which according to your error will be found in the following location:

/Users/lorenzojoaquin/.ebcli-virtual-env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_distutils_hack/**init**.py

Then scroll down to line 194 which is quite close to the bottom and change the line of code from:

```
f'spec_for_{name}'
```

to

```
'spec_for_{}'.format(name)
```

Then save the file and run the command.